# How to add the css in lightning component style class

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, slds, styleclass

I am using a third party lightning component in 'lightning Flow' to display dynamic questions. Some checkboxes are getting displayed via that lightning component but their width is set to 100%. I inspected the element in google chrome and found out the below code. The width:100% needs to be commented out to fix the issue.

```
slds-form-element_stacked:not([class*="slds-size"]), .slds-form_stacked 
.slds-form-element:not([class*="slds-size"]), .slds-form_horizontal .slds- 
form-element_stacked:not([class*="slds-size"])

{ /* width: 100%; */
     flex-basis: 100%; }
```

How do I add the above code in STYLE class of lightning component to reflect the change?

Comment: Is the third-party component you are using installed via the AppExchange? Do you have access to its source code in your org?

Comment: No not from appexchange but from google site. Here is the link:
https://sites.google.com/view/flowunofficial/flow-screen-components/fsc-dynamic-question

Comment: Not sure what source code should I have access to make it work but I can see  helper, style, design, js file. Still not able to locate where the above code (posted in the question) lies? Need some guidance.

Comment: Easy solution: add a custom CSS to DynamicQuestionChild component. Better solution: edit DynamicQuestionChild component main file changing the classes used inside the form and/or the structure of the file.

Comment: .THIS.slds-form-element_stacked .slds-form_stacked .slds-form_horizontal  {
    width: 3%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}